# Hosted Feature Layer In Portal Having A Double Underscore In SHAPE__AREA and SHAPE__LENGTH

Tags: file-geodatabase, arcgis-portal, hosted-feature-layer

I am publishing a Hosted Feature Layer from an existing gdb in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 and in this gdb my SHAPE_AREA and SHAPE_LENGTH fields have one underscore in it.

[image]

But when I go to portal, or bring in the Hosted Feature Layer into ArcGIS Pro, it has a double underscore "__" in the field which prevent users from adding in new points, lines, or polygons to the Hosted Feature Layer from a shapefile or feature from another gdb/sde.

[image]

When I export the Hosted Feature Layer from portal to a gdb the double underscore goes away and is back to a single.

Is there a way to have a Hosted Feature Layer to have a single underscore?